# How to export the reference list for a given paper using Google Scholar?

Tags: citations, literature-search, google-scholar

Google Scholar allows you to do forward search via cited by - that is, you can get a list of references that cite a given reference. Is there any way to do backward search, i.e. get a list of references cited BY a given reference?

I realize that you can always click the reference, go to the journal page, and likely get the reference list there, but I am wondering if there is any way to do it within the context of Google Scholar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Weirdly, I don't think that Google Scholar provides that feature, even though they clearly parse and store this information internally. This does indeed sound like a nice feature to have access to.

Comment: They have this information, but it may not be fast or easy to retrieve it, depending on the specific format that they use.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Google Scholar only provides the list of publications that cite a given reference.

However, if you have access to Web of Science, to look up a list of references cited in a given publication, you can use the "Cited References" tool.

Note that some journals are not indexed by Web of Science. In that case, you will need to look up the bibliography in the full text of the publication.